# Need Assistance with React-Select Multi-Select Grouped Options

Tags: react-select

I am using react-select multi-select component with grouped options. I would like to select all the options under the group when the group header is clicked.

This I have accomplished and works fine

```
const Group = (props: any) => {
    const onClick = () => props.selectProps.onChange(props.options);

    return (
        <chakraComponents.Group
            {...props}
            headingProps={{ ...props.headingProps, onClick }}
        />
    );
};
```

What I would like to accomplish is:

- Append to the already selected options instead of just selecting the options on group header click.
- Decrease the count number from the group header when the option gets selected.
- Show the count of options(in header label) that matched the search criteria.

[Here is the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/chakra-accordion-react-seelct-forked-893t56?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A7%2C25&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00073b6hw95lmndi%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00023b6ho78wdfl8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00043b6h2ttbycgy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00063b6h4ivz79fp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltmor1lu00023b6ho78wdfl8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00023b6ho78wdfl8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmoxnt500023b6hxvlgiepr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A25%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A25%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltmoxnt500023b6hxvlgiepr%2522%257D%252C%2522cltmor1lu00063b6h4ivz79fp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00063b6h4ivz79fp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmowhti00rw3b6h2g6lq3mj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltmowhti00rw3b6h2g6lq3mj%2522%257D%252C%2522cltmor1lu00043b6h2ttbycgy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmor1lu00043b6h2ttbycgy%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltmou8zr00o23b6h35qd41fw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cltmou93o000tdii34m539kr7%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltmou8zr00o23b6h35qd41fw%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)